# Saving pictures in specified folder in Android

Tags: java, android, camera

This is my first post here at Stackoverflow and I have my fingers crossed that you may be able to help me.

I've recently started learning Android and have decided a simple app which takes a photo and then shows the photo to the user within the app would be a good place to start.

However, after following the guide over at the Android Developer site (http://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics.html) I just can't seem to get the image to display.

I receive the error:

> Unable to decode stream: java.io.FileNotFoundException: file:/storage/emulated/0/Pictures/JPEG_20160101_163802_1697759335.jpg: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)

I can see that the photo has been saved in the default camera folder, not the path I had specified (as copied/pasted from the developer tutorial).

I would be hugely grateful if anyone could help me figure out how to either save the photo in the specified file, or to get the saved location back from the camera app.

```
    package uk.co.c2digital.futurefoto;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

/**
 * The following code is based on the following article: http://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics.html
 */

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Log.v("MainActivity", "App Started");
    }





    /**
     * This block of code launches the default camera application
     */

    static final int REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO = 1;

    public void dispatchTakePictureIntent(View view) {

        Log.v("MainActivity", "dispatchTakePictureIntent() function started");

        Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        // Ensure that there's a camera activity to handle the intent
        if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {

            // Out success result to log
            Log.v("MainActivity", "Camera app found");

            // Create the File where the photo should go
            File photoFile = null;
            try {
                photoFile = createImageFile();
                Log.v("MainActivity","Image will be saved to: " + photoFile);
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                // Error occurred while creating the File
                Toast.makeText(this, "Unable to save image", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Log.v("MainActivity", "Error while attempting to run createImageFile()");
            }
            // Continue only if the File was successfully created
            if (photoFile != null) {
                Log.v("MainActivity","File created");
                takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,
                        Uri.fromFile(photoFile));
                startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO);




            }
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Unable to launch camera app", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Log.v("MainActivity","Unable to find camera app");
        }
    }

    /**
     * End of camera launch code
     */


    /**
     * This block of code creates a unique file name for captured photos to prevent naming collisions
     */


    String mCurrentPhotoPath;

    public File createImageFile() throws IOException {

        Log.v("MainActivity","createImageFile() functions started");

        // Create an image file name
        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
        String imageFileName = "JPEG_" + timeStamp + "_";
        File storageDir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
                Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
        File image = File.createTempFile(
                imageFileName,  /* prefix */
                ".jpg",         /* suffix */
                storageDir      /* directory */
        );

        // Save a file: path for use with ACTION_VIEW intents
        mCurrentPhotoPath = "file:" + image.getAbsolutePath();


        return image;
    }


    /**
     * End of unique file name code
     */


    /**
     * This block of code decodes and scales the photo and displays in photoView
     */



    public void setPic() {

        Log.v("MainActivity","setPic() function started");

        ImageView mImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageViewer);

        // Get the dimensions of the View
        int targetW = mImageView.getWidth();
        int targetH = mImageView.getHeight();

        // Get the dimensions of the bitmap
        BitmapFactory.Options bmOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        bmOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        BitmapFactory.decodeFile(mCurrentPhotoPath, bmOptions);
        int photoW = bmOptions.outWidth;
        int photoH = bmOptions.outHeight;

        // Determine how much to scale down the image
        int scaleFactor = Math.min(photoW/targetW, photoH/targetH);

        // Decode the image file into a Bitmap sized to fill the View
        bmOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
        bmOptions.inSampleSize = scaleFactor;
        bmOptions.inPurgeable = true;

        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(mCurrentPhotoPath, bmOptions);
        mImageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    }

    /**
     * End of photo scaling code
     */


    /**
     * THis block of code allows the created photo to be made available to the photo gallery
     */


    private void galleryAddPic() {

        Log.v("MainActivity", "galleryAddPic() function started");

        Intent mediaScanIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE);
        File f = new File(mCurrentPhotoPath);
        Uri contentUri = Uri.fromFile(f);
        mediaScanIntent.setData(contentUri);
        this.sendBroadcast(mediaScanIntent);
    }


    /**
     * End of gallery code
     */


    /**
     * This block of code handles the responce from the cameras intent
     */

    public void onActivityResult(int RequestCode, int ResultCode, Intent data) {

        Log.v("MainActivity","onActivityResult() function started");

        if (RequestCode == REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO) {

            Log.v("MainActivity","RequestCode matched REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO");

            if (ResultCode == RESULT_OK) {

                Log.v("MainActivity","ResultCode was OK");

                 // galleryAddPic();
                  setPic();

            } else {

                Log.v("MainActivity","ResultCode was not OK");
                Log.v("MainActivity","ResultCode was: " + ResultCode);
            }


        } else {

            Log.v("MainActivity","RequestCode did not equal REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO");
            Log.v("MainActivity","Request Code was: " + RequestCode);
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: there is a guide here -- https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Accessing-the-Camera-and-Stored-Media

Comment: Check this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oNI8clwlRCI) out. It will help you.

Comment: @helldawg - appreciate the link but the narration is in Greek which, unfortunately, I do not speak.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the approach I use:

```
Uri newPhotoUri;
public void takePhoto() {
    // create Intent to take a picture and return control to the calling application
    Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

    newPhotoUri = Uri.fromFile(new File(filename)); // create a file to save the image
    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, newPhotoUri); // set the image file name

    // start the image capture Intent
    startActivityForResult(intent, CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE);
}
```

and then:

```
/**
 * Called when returning from the camera request.
 */
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Received camera activity result");
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            String resultPath = "";
            if (data == null) {
                if (this.newPhotoUri != null) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Intent data is null, trying with uri " + this.newPhotoUri.getPath());
                    resultPath = this.newPhotoUri.getPath();
                } else {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Intent data and photo Uri are null, exiting");
                    return;
                }
            } else {
                // Image captured and saved to fileUri specified in the Intent
                Log.d(TAG, "Image saved to: " + data.getData());
                resultPath = data.getData().toString();
            }
            // process resultPath
        } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
            // User cancelled the image capture
            Log.d(TAG, "User cancelled");
        } else {
            // Image capture failed
        }
    }
}
```

With some devices, the media store location is not guaranteed to be used, so this is more of a practical approach.

Comment: @jihonora - Thanks, took me a little while to learn what to put in filename (currently using: "Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "image1.jpeg" for the moment).